# How to fix this issue "no suitable node (scheduling constraints not satisfied on 1 node)" in docker swarm while deploying registry?

Tags: docker, docker-swarm, docker-registry, docker-swarm-mode

I have a docker swarm in a virtual machine with 2 core 4GB ram Centos.

In the swarm when I deploy docker private registry (registry 2.6.4) it shows service status as **pending** forever.
I used 
**`docker service ps <<registry_name>>`**

And when i inspect using **`docker inspect <<task_id>>`** in message I got this
 ***"no suitable node (scheduling constraints not satisfied on 1 node)".***

I tried service restart and redeployment.

How to fix this?

Comment: Did you find a solution for this?

Comment: No, That setup didn't worked. I reinstalled docker setup in the machine.

Answer (score 20):

I often run into this problem when there is a mismatch between the node labels defined in the compose file and the ones defined in the actual node, either because I set a wrong label (e.g. a typo) or simply forgot to label nodes at all.

**To label nodes:**

1) For each target node do:

`docker-machine ssh <manager_node_name> 'docker node update --label-add <label_name>=<label_value> <target_node_name>'`

2) Make sure they match the ones defined in the compose file.

3) restart docker service in manager node

**for example:**

compose file:

```
 dummycontainer:
    image: group/dummyimage
    deploy:
      mode: replicated
      replicas: 1
      placement:
        constraints: [node.labels.dummy_label == dummy]
      restart_policy:
        condition: on-failure
```

assuming that I want to deploy this replica in a node called *dummy_node*:

```
docker-machine ssh manager_node 'docker node update --label-add dummy_label=dummy dummy_node'
```

and restart docker in the manager node.

Finally, if you deploy you should expect dummycontainer running in dummy_node, assuming that the label was correctly set in both steps. Otherwise it is expectable to see the error you are getting.

Best regards

Comment: Hi, Thanks for the response. But I got this issue in normal service create without stack.

Comment: Thanks for the help. My issue was a simple typo in the compose file. `mode.role == manager` instead of `node.role == manager`

Comment: This was my issue had to give a complete hostname.

Answer (score 6):

I had a similar problem while deploying service, check what is the availability of node, by `docker node ls` and check if nodes are not set to `drain` and update to `active` using `docker node update --availability active <node-id>`

which will allow swarm to run containers on the nodes for that service.

Answer (score 0):

I encountered this error when attempting to deploy `viz` on a Raspberry Pi Swarm.

It turns out there is a [specific version for ARM architectures](https://hub.docker.com/r/dockersamples/visualizer/#running-on-arm):

```
docker service create \
  --name=viz \
  --publish=8080:8080/tcp \
  --constraint=node.role==manager \
  --mount=type=bind,src=/var/run/docker.sock,dst=/var/run/docker.sock \
  alexellis2/visualizer-arm:latest
```

Comment: This was our issue. We were building on an Apple Silicon machine and encountered this issue due to the architecture being different.

Answer (score 0):

Another way would be to remove the `reservations` unless you have it set for all.